# Exchange - Push notifications using Exchange Web Services

Tags: exchangewebservices

I was looking into implementation of Exchange/O365 mail notification service using the [exchange push notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx). To subscribe to notifications one has to use the [subscribe web service/REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566188(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection3) with a call back URL. Upon successful subscription Exchange will call the URL with notification events for the user.

Suppose the call back URL will be hosted as a Web service in our environment (cloud), it has to be publicly accessible. That raises security concerns. I browsed through MSDN and couldn't find any way to secure this (security key/tokens/auth)call back  notification event.

I want to know what are the options available to make this notifications in secure way OR is the push notifications approach not recommended at all in such scenarios.  Streaming notifications approach is not possible because it requires admin credentials and and the third party client who would like to use email notifications via our service will reject such an option.

Do let me know if any clarifications is required.

Thanks in Advance!